# Entity Framework making double a nullable property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a property called `TotalVolume` which is a `Double`. In the code-first approach when the database is constructed the property `TotalVolume` has got a `Not Null` value by default. I want to make the property `TotalVolume` accept `Null` values too.

I am using FluentAPI, and the change I made is as follows:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(p => p.TotalVolume)
            .IsRequired(false);
```

I end up with the following error when I `Add-Migration`:

> The property 'TotalVolume' on entity type 'Employee' cannot be marked as nullable/optional because the type of the property is 'double' which is not a nullable type. Any property can be marked as non-nullable/required, but only properties of nullable types and which are not part of primary key can be marked as nullable/optional.

Thereafter, I tried the following approach, where I made the following change in my `Employee` Model.

```
    public double? TotalVolume{ get; set; }
```

However, when I updated the database, the datatype for `TotalVolume` has changed to a `float`. I want the datatype to still remain as `double`.

Comment: Payment or totalvolume you mean ?

Comment: typo it should be TotalVolume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float` in SQL is a 64bit value and corresponds to `double` in .Net, so it seems to be working as expected.

Entity Framework maps these types so that they have the same meaning but it doesn't require they have the same names.

Comment: Ok. Do you know how I could make the property TotalVolume to Allow Nulls ?

Comment: Ok, my initial question was how to make the double value (TotalVolume) accept nulls ? Do you know how I could do this ?

Comment: @Illep it looks ok. Check if the column in the DB created this way is Nullable. In SQL the ability to set a float to null doesn't change the type of the column. It's an attribute on that column.

Comment: @Illep have you tried inserting a row with TotalVolume set to null?

Comment: In the SQL management studio , usually there's a tick on the side that indicates if it accepts null or not. At the moment the tick is off.